# in constructor, no matching function call to

Tags: c++

My error

```
gridlist.h: In constructor ‘GridList::GridList(WINDOW*, int, int, int, int, int)’:
gridlist.h:11:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘Window::Window()’
gridlist.h:11:47: note: candidates are:
window.h:13:3: note: Window::Window(WINDOW*, int, int, int, int, int)
```

My code

```
GridList(WINDOW *parent = stdscr, int colors = MAG_WHITE, int height = GRIDLIST_HEIGHT, int width = GRIDLIST_WIDTH, int y = 0, int x = 0) 
: Window(parent, colors, height, width, y, x) {
    this->m_buttonCount = -1;
    m_maxButtonsPerRow = ((GRIDLIST_WIDTH)/(BUTTON_WIDTH+BUTTON_SPACE_BETWEEN));
    this->m_buttons = new Button *[50];
    refresh();
}
```

I am a little unsure of what exactly it is trying to tell me and what I am doing wrong. I am passing the correct variable types to the class and the correct number of parameters. However it says I am trying to call `Window::Window()` with no parameters. Thanks in advance for any help.

The class Button compiles just fine, and is almost exactly the same.

```
Button(WINDOW *parent = 0, int colors = STD_SCR, int height = BUTTON_WIDTH, int width = BUTTON_HEIGHT, int y = 0, int x = 0) 
: Window(parent, colors, height, width, y, x) {
            this->refresh();
        }
```

Comment: Ohh, and I am using g++ 4.6.1 on linux.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Are you sure that the line numbers in the error match the code you're showing here?

Comment: You could try including the definition of GridList. And Window.

Comment: Is it possible that in the body of your ctor code, which isn't here, you have some call to `Window::Window()`?

Comment: @Cameron yes this is the code that the line numbers point to. I don't understand considering I have many of other classes setup the exact same way, they compile. I have even copied over the class's constructor and just changed the name to GridList, but to no avail.

Comment: I guess the compiler couldn't find the declaration of Window. maybe it's in a namespace or you failed to include it?

Comment: @Alex it found the declaration. The compiler told me the candidates, if I wouldn't have included it, it wouldn't be able to do that...

Comment: Could it be your `Button` construction?

Comment: @chris I don't believe so, it looks almost exactly the same as this constructor.

Comment: @user1541925, [This example](http://ideone.com/sPYRW) shows what I mean. It just looks like it could be a culprit, but I'm not sure how it would complain about the base class (assuming `Window` *is* your base class), unless you have something like `Button::Button() : Window(){}`. I would think it would complain about `Button.h` then, though.

Comment: Just looking at this is a bit hard. Normally you wouldn't need to, but could you link to a pastebin or something of your `Window.h`, `Button.h`, and `Gridlist.h` files, as well as any others that are needed for this to compile? I'd kind of like to give it a shot with a full sample.

Comment: The `Button` class has no `delete` anywhere in its code, except for in the destructor.

Comment: `window.h` `gridlist.h` `button.h` http://pastebin.com/Zm0J80P8

Comment: @user1541925, Sorry, that was extraneous. I was just making the fact that there was no default constructor very explicit. It gives the same error if you leave out any trace of the default constructor.

Comment: if you have git the whole project is located at `https://github.com/Retribute/grutu.git` this error has been driving me crazy.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've gotten it down to where I get the same error, and indeed it is the line initializing the base, which is very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GridList` class has a member variable of type `Window`. Since all members are (default if unspecified) initialized **before** the body of the constructor, yours looks similar to this in reality:

```
GridList::GridList (...)
 : Window(...), m_tendMenu() //<--here's the problem you can't see
```

Your member variable is being default initialized, but your `Window` class has no default constructor, hence the problem. To fix it, initialize your member variable in your member initializers:

```
GridList::GridList (...)
 : Window(...), m_tendMenu(more ...), //other members would be good here, too
```

The reason your `Button` class works is because it doesn't have a member of type `Window`, and thus, nothing being default-initialized when it can't be.

Comment: You hit the nail right on the head. I forgot all about even adding that to my code. Thank you chris, you have been very helpful.

Comment: @user1541925, I'm so happy I figured that out. It was confusing me like nothing else.

Comment: good thing, its just like writing a story, you can't proof your own work. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you just calling the constructor in the initlizer list ? usually you initialize member variables there so there would be member variable of type window there.

```
GridList(WINDOW *parent = stdscr, int colors = MAG_WHITE, 
  int height = GRIDLIST_HEIGHT, int width = GRIDLIST_WIDTH, int y = 0, int x = 0)
  : m_window(parent, colors, height, width, y, x) { }
```

Comment: Presumably `GridList` is derived from `Window`.

Comment: Also if this were the case, wouldn't you want something more like> :m_window(Window(parent, colors, height, width, y, x))